# Is it possible to configure the Send to context menu to "send" files to an already open email message?

Tags: windows, email

This could come in handy when trying to attach files that are deeply "buried" or scattered within the directory tree to a reply email.

I'm using Thunderbird as the email client (if that matters) but I'm asking more in general.

Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't Thunderbird allow you to simply drag and drop files onto open mail windows to attach them?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does, but sometimes it is not convenient enough.
I was hoping to find a way to browse one's files and folders and add the relevant files to an already open message windows as one goes. All the other file attaching methods are fine too, but sometimes it is just simpler and more productive to add multiple files from different locations in a click of button as you browse. I've researched the topic a little, and it seems that currently it is not possible to do that, at least not in any built in way.